# Primary key on linked table

Tags: ms-access

I've a table **linked** to Outlook Contacts. It's useful to use it this way as it stays always up to date.
But I need it to have a primary key as it's useful for better query management. (Eg., if I'm not wrong, you can have an editable further query with two tables only if these two tables are joined on primary key fields.)

I couldn't get rid of it, and I see following way only but it's not actually satisfying me:
create a table equal to "outlook contacts" but static, manually (or with VBA) update it starting from the linked one. But it seems quite complicated.

**Edit:**
For better clarity let's assume the linked table is named `OutlookContacts` and, for easiness, has following 5 fields:

```
Company
LastName
FirstName
Email
MobileNumber
```

Comment: I linked my Microsoft Outlook Contacts (local Outlook 2013 Contacts) into a Microsoft Access 2013 Database for testing right now and saw that the resulting linked table already has a primary key field named `Normalized Subject`.

Comment: Strange, cannot find "Normalized Subject" field in my linked outlook contacts. I'm using office 2016. Do others have same experience?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to help solve your issue is this:

1. Build a make table query that selects from the linked table into a new tables. i.e.:

   ```
   SELECT 
       t1.Company
       , t1.LastName
       , t1.FirstName
       , t1.Email
       , t1.MobileNumber
       , COUNT(*) AS RowID
   INTO NewTbl   
   FROM yourTable t1
   INNER JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.Email>=t2.Email
   GROUP BY
       t1.Company
       , t1.LastName
       , t1.FirstName
       , t1.Email
       , t1.MobileNumber
   ```

This is just a sample query to show you how to get a rowid into your new table as your run the query.

2.Then run another saved query:

```
ALTER TABLE NewTbl ADD PRIMARY KEY (RowiD)
```

3. Then create a marco for AutoExec that fires both of these sequentially when anyone opens the database. BOOM solved.

Comment: @Andrew The make table query is taking your result set and then creating a unique identifer. It does an inner join to itself and then compares it to come value. Youll need to adjust to your table (i dont know the table specifics) it was given as an example. You shoul dbe able to "plug and play" with it as you really only need to understand the technique. IDK if there is already a unique identifier on your table or not, so I thought I should be safe and create one in the make table query

Comment: thanks, but still cannot understand the meaning of "taskname" field. I've edited my question with added part so that you can reference to my table field name

Comment: @Andrew see my edited post. Youll still need to replace "yourtable" with the actual table name. Youre going to need to learn how to adapt code samples to your example. It will help you out quite a bit in the future.

Comment: thanks I tried, but still not working. Added RowID field is not unique. Also why to put "ON t1.Email>=t2.Email" ? I think you assume Email field is unique, but what if it's null in some records? In outlook it's not mandatory field

Comment: you could always wrap email in NZ() function

Comment: @Andrew Also, what would a composite key be in this table? Meaning are there two columns when combined create a unique Identifer?